# Access ViewContext.ViewBag without editing the .cshtml view file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to render a view to html string using the `RenderViewToString` method below. When calling the `viewResult.View.Render` and passing the viewContext, it results in the ViewBag being null in the .cshtml view. Example code of my renderer:

```
  public string RenderViewToString(ControllerContext context, string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(context, viewName, null);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, viewData, new TempDataDictionary(), sw);

            var thisViewBagHasValues = ViewBag;
            var thisViewBagIsNull = viewContext.ViewBag;

            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

I think by calling the `@ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag` in the .cshtml file, we can then access the `ViewBag` data. However, is there a way to access the `ViewBag` in the .cshtml file without editing the view file? Such as setting a value to the `ViewContext.ViewBag` before calling the renderer?

Comment: So, *have* you tried `viewContext.ViewBag = ViewBag`?

Comment: @haim770 Yes. The value is `readonly`